# Can't find the right packages for robot3d installation

Tags: linux, installation, kubuntu, packages

I have a problem with the installation of robot3d. For ubunutu users it should be an easy task. But it doesn't work. On my system runs kubunutu 11.04.

The installation manual says that I should do the following:

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:robot3d-team/ppa-robot3d
  sudo aptitude update
  sudo aptitude install robot3d-dev yarp-bin delta3d-apps
```

I did this, but I can't find the right packages. I think the new name for robot3d-dev is robot3d-data. Yarp-bin still exists.

But I have no idea how to install delta3d-apps. I can't find this package and no packages that looks similar.

Maybe someone can help me.

Regards

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: The packages are not available. Perhaps it is only supported for an other distribution. Is this possible?